# Using multiple, MySqlConnection objects concurrently, for the same connection string, throws exceptions

Tags: c#, mysql, multithreading, thread-safety, database-connection

My code looks like this:

```
void SomeFuncCalledConcurrently()
{
    using(var connection = new MySqlConnection(mConnectionString))
    {
    connection.Open();

    //DoStuff

    connection.Close();
    }
}
```

SomeFuncCalledConcurrently is called by multiple threads at once.

The problem is I get an exception that the connection is already open, even tho as far as I am aware, the connection pool is thread-safe, which means that I only need to create the MySqlConnection objects for each thread.

This is what I get:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The connection is already open.'

Could the connection object be getting reused behind the scenes, due to having the same connection string? If that's the case, is there a way to disable this?

Comment: That should really not happen, connection pool is thread-safe. Do you call `connection.Open` anywhere else in the function? Can you [edit] and post the rest of the code for that function?

Comment: Post the full exception details, including the call stack (as text, not image): http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/